# ListBox not populated in WP7 after values return from web request

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, binding

I am trying to build a simple application for WP7 from scratch. The List Box in MainPage.xaml looks like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" >
    <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding result}" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
               </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

In order to populate result and its elements, name and description, I need to fetch the values from a web server that responds with json for the get request I send. Since I need to make different calls to the server that respond with different json objects, I am maintaining different .cs files for each, independant of mainpage.cs (where i only initialize, define MainPage_Loaded and MainListBox_SelectionChanged). All the data is fetched and processed in the individual .cs files. 
Now the problem is that when I make the httpwebrequest and the reponse is retrieved, the UI is loaded well before that. As I understand from other posts the BeginGetResponse becomes a background process and the UI is loaded to keep it reponsive. So to summarize before the web request is returned with the data from the server, the UI is loaded as blank since the data is not populated. Now I cannot use the Dispatcher to populate since I am not in MainPage.cs and so can't access the List Box directly. I tried callback also but with no success. Please help

MainPage.cs:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded +=new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
    }

    private void MainListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MainListBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailsPage.xaml?selectedItem=" + MainListBox.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));

        MainListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    // Load data for the ViewModel Items
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)            
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();            
    }
}
```

LoadData() essentially initializes the request parameters, prepares URI and send the HTTP request to another function in another class (executeRequest.cs file) that gets the reponse and processes the request into objects that I could map to:

```
public void decodeJson<E>(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        request.Method = "GET";
        var reqresult = (IAsyncResult)request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallback<E>, request);
    }

    public void ResponseCallback<E>(IAsyncResult reqresult)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)reqresult.AsyncState;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(reqresult);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (contents.ToString().StartsWith("{\"jsonrpc"))
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(contents)))
                {
                    Type typeofe = typeof(E);
                    var deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(E));
                    E element = (E)deserializer.ReadObject(ms);
                    populateResult<E>(element);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In populateResult I am trying to populate the UI. But by the time control enters BeginGetResponse my UI is populated and in populateResult since the List Box, MainListBox is not accessible I cannot use the dispatcher to *refresh* the UI with the new data

To give more info, result is an ObservableCollection of a class that contains different properties that come in from the json

The populateResult is very simple:

```
private void processResult<E>(E element)
    {
        //Checking for the type of result so that I can map
        string typeis = typeof(E).ToString();
        if (typeis.EndsWith("MyViewModel")
            {
              App.ViewModel.result = (element as MyViewModel).result;
              ???
            }
    }
```

Probably I should admit this (???) is where I am stuck. The result collection is updated but not in the UI. The UI is still blank and I cannot access the MainListBox from populateRsult to update. Hope it is clear. Else please tell me

With due courtesy let me also provide with MyViewModel and the SubViewModel

MyViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {            
        this.result = new ObservableCollection<SubViewModel>();
    }        
    public ObservableCollection<SubViewModel> result { get; set; }
    private string _sampleProperty = "Sample Runtime Property Value";
    public string SampleProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _sampleProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            _sampleProperty = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SampleProperty");
        }
    }

    public bool IsDataLoaded
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public void LoadData()
    {
        //Initialize all the parameters
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format
            (uri with parameters);            
        request.Method = "GET";
        //call the decide json to get the reponse and parse it
        executeRequest execReq = new executeRequest();
        execReq.decodeJson<MyViewModel>(request);

        this.IsDataLoaded = true;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (null != PropertyChanged)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

SubviewModel:

```
public class SubViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private string _name;
    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("name");
        }
    }

    private string _description;
    public string description
    {
        get
        {
            return _description;
        }
        set
        {
            _description = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("description");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName) 
    {
        if (null != PropertyChanged) 
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for populateResult? Rest of your code should be ok if you have found BeginGetResponse actually downloads the data correctly. You need to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to update the collection of objects databound to the ListBox.

Comment: Updated! Can you please help now ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything about how you're binding what to your listbox.  you have a binding to `result` in your xaml, but aren't showing the declaration of what it actually is.  If it is an observable collection, your `populateResult` method should be pretty trivial, just updating the observable collection's contents with new data.

If you are re-creating the observable collection in populate result, instead of just changing its content, that could be your problem.

**update:**

The biggest issue (from what i can tell from your updated code) is that your view model isn't firing a property change when you set `result`.  so you need to do one of two things:

a) add property change support on `result` like the view model class has for `SampleProperty`, so that when it gets modified, bindings see the change:

```
private ObservableCollection<SubViewModel> _result = new ObservableCollection<SubViewModel>();
public ObservableCollection Result    
{
    get
    {
        return _result;
    }        
    set
    {
        _result = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Result");
    }
}

// -- elsewhere --
private void processResult<E>(E element)    
{        
    // (why were you using the type **name** to check the 
    // type of the result instead of just using `as`?)
    var model = element as MyViewModel;
    if (model != null)
    {              
        App.ViewModel.Result = model.result;              
    }    
}
```

b) or you need to not *set* `result`, but modify its *contents* since it is an observable collection already:

```
private void processResult<E>(E element)    
{        
    var model = element as MyViewModel;
    if (model != null)
    {              
        // result is an ObservableCollection, so just modify its contents.  
        // anything bound to it will see the changes via collection change notifications
        App.ViewModel.result.ClearItems();
        foreach (var x in model.result)
            App.ViewModel.result.Add(x);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Hi John, regarding your question "why were you using the type name to check the type of the result instead of just using as?" is because I have several other Models in my code and not just MyViewModel. So the element returned can be any of them (I could call decode json from anywhere). So I need to check its type before casting it to the relevant type Also, I plan on taking a) of your suggestion. So I just had a trivial (I guess) question. So once the NotifyPropertyChanged event is fired will the UI update itself automatically? or do I need to manually do anything else?

Comment: Hi John, option a) isn't working. The UI is not updated. I still see the blank page even though the response from the web server succeeds

Comment: I also observed on debugging that before and after the result is populated, PropertyChanged is always null. So the control never enters `PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));` for result property. I am sure we are missing a very trivial thing here.

Comment: if `propertychanged` is null, that means nobody is listening.  did you change the names of your properties and your bindings so that they all match?  do you have any warnings/errors in output about binding?  otherwise, using option B, where you just update the contents of the colleciton might make more sense.  You could always hard code some entries into the collection to start as well, to make sure that you're actually binding correctly and those items show up.

Comment: Thanks John. Mission accomplished and problem is fixed! Problem was with name changes as you guessed it –